# Finding an equation when roots are given

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Find the equation whose roots are equal to numbers
$$\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n + 1},\ \sin^2\frac{2\pi}{2n + 1},\ \sin^2\frac{3\pi}{2n + 1},\dots,\ \sin^2\frac{n\pi}{2n + 1}$$

The question looked intriguing and now with the hints provided here I can take it forward.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check the original question... It was probably not the one you are asking. One possible (and trivial) answer to your question can just be
$$
(z-\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n+1})(z-\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{2n+1})\cdots(z-\sin^2\frac{n\pi}{2n+1})=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $n = 1$ your numbers are

$$\sin^2 {\pi \over 3},\ \sin^2 {2\pi \over 3},\ \sin^2 {3\pi \over 3},\ $$

whereas $$\sin^2 {\pi \over 3}=\sin^2 {2\pi \over 3},$$
[image]

The similar situation is for all $n$: $n$ pairs of equal values:
[image]

Now, all red points $z = \cos \phi + \mathbb i\sin \phi$ represent all solutions of the equation
$$z^{2n+1} = -1,$$
i.e.
$$(\cos \phi + \mathbb i\sin \phi)^{2n+1} = -1$$

Consider to expand the left-hand side and then separate real and imaginary parts of the equation.